# how can i find H(z) in this matlab code

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

i want to find H(z) in this code and print it.but i don't know how can i?

```
n=-11:11;
lp=(1/3)*sinc((1/3)*n);
wh=rectwin(23);
b=lp.*wh';
figure(1);
k=0:22;
stem(k,b);
title('N=23 FIR Filter impulse Response');
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Mag');
figure(2);
[h,w]=freqz(b,1,1024);
plot(w/pi,20*log10(abs(h)));
grid;
title('LPF FIR -rectwin  N=23 frequency response');
axis([0 1 -100 10]);
```

Comment: Note that matlab is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

For a FIR filter with coefficients `b(1)`, `b(2)`, ..., the transfer function is the sum of `b(k)*z^(-k+1)` for k from 1 to len(b).  See https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/FIR_Transfer_Function.html (The difference of `+1` in the power of z is because Matlab arrays are indexed starting at 1, but the vector `b` in the link starts at `b_0`.)